# PHP Curl need help - 2Captcha

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha, 2captcha

We are writing a bot with Curl but we are stuck at a point. There is a v3 captcha for 2Captcha, but access to the page it needs to reach is only possible with cookies, so a session needs to be opened.

2Captcha is trying to access that URL as a guest, but we need to define cookies within 2Captcha. Is there any way to do that?

Cookies identification